# Which Grant Type of identity server 4 should be used for ecommerce application

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect, razor-pages

I am creating an ecommerce B2C application using .NET core 3.1 with Razor pages.
**Project structure:**

- Api (.net core)
- Authentication server (centralized server using identity server 4)
- Razor pages (will contain all the UI elements like product pages or cart page)

Now we all know that in ecommerce app we allow the customer to see the product list page without logged in but when user click on add to cart button we redirect the user to login page. I am looking for the same functionality.

Can anybody suggest me what grant type I should use in this case ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, you can use anonymous token flow for showcasing your product lists.

Comment: Can you explain more I haven't used anonymous token flow ? what it is ? Does it comes with Identity server ?

Comment: Hi, as you want your product list to be pubic, you can allow those end points to get accessed by  anonymous users.  When an user has landed in your site you can give him an anonymous token with that token he can access any end point allowed for anonymous user. Or you can simply ignore any authentication for those endpoints.

Comment: That's obvious but I am looking for Grant Type when doing authentication using Identity server 4 . I cannot use ResourceOwner or ClientCredentials. So any idea what Grant Type I should specify in my Config.

Comment: _[Interactive Clients](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#interactive-clients) ... is the most common type of client scenario: web applications, ..._

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Thank you this above link looks good to me. Can you please provide any reference code on any website if you know.

Comment: You can find the samples [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/samples/Quickstarts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since razor pages runs on the server side (is a confidential client and thusly can securely store a Client Secret) you can use the **Authorization Code** grant type or the **Hybrid** Grant Type.

Comment: What if I wish to use Angular instead of Razor pages ? In that case what will be the grant type ? I think it will be Implicit. What's your suggestion on this ?

Comment: Yes you are correct! It is very important that you use the Implicit Grant type on SPAs (or any client that lives on the client side). Your security in the Implicit Grant type comes from the token changing periodically not that 3rd parties can´t access tokens. This means that other people can access your token, but since it will be refreshed/changes every x amount of time, the person stealing the token will have a limited amount of time to do any damage. You should consider implementing automatic log off in this scenario.

Comment: Yes, automatic log off is must here.